# XAML Windows Store hierarchical View

Tags: winrt-xaml, hierarchy

I want to have a hierarchical display of my items.

My items for instance looking like this pseudo-class:

```
public class ListItem
{
  public string Title {get; set;}
  public ObservableCollection<ListItem> Children {get; set;}
}
```

And I want to have them displayed like this:
[image]

I don't want to collapse or expand items - I only wanna a different margin for different levels.

How can I achieve this in XAML and Windows Store Apps? (I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096168/listviews-item-insert-animations-in-winrt/14098474) on Stackoverflow but it allows me only to have 2 Levels)

edit:
I looked also at the TreeView in the XAML Toolkit, but I didn't find a way to disable the "expand-collapse".

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi! I haven't tried a lot, because I have no clue where to start. 
I tried the XAML Toolkit TreeView, but I couldn't disable the expand/collapse.
My only approach now is to get the whole hierarchy up and count the depth of the current item and bind the margin to this depth - but this is not a very nice solution and performance will be bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers!
I found a solution that suits my needs.

I followed this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/Hierarchical-Linq-Queries) and sort my list in the correct order. Then I wrote a LevelToMargin-Converter which converts the level of the item to a margin. For example:

Level 0 -> Margin: 0 
Level 1 -> Margin: 20 
Level 2 -> Margin: 40 
...

LevelToMargin-Converter:

```
public class LevelToMarginConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var v = (value as int?)*20;
        return new Thickness(System.Convert.ToDouble(v),0, 0, 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var t = value is Thickness ? (Thickness) value : new Thickness();
        return t.Left / 20;
    }
}
```

Then I bind my Level to the margin of the ListItem

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="GradingCriteriaListDataTemplate"
              x:Name="GradingCriteriaListDataTemplate">
    <Grid Width="400">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Padding="5,5,5,5"
                Background="#eaeaea"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                Margin="{Binding Level, Converter={StaticResource  LevelToMarginConverter}}"
                Grid.Column="0">

            <Border Margin="15,5,5,5"
                    Height="50"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    BorderBrush="Yellow"
                    BorderThickness="10,0,0,0">
                <StackPanel Margin="20,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                               Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

It works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to deal whit this is to use `ListView` and `DataTemplateSelector` along with wrappers.
My suggestion is you will have Class that represents each item in `ListView`.
Than in `DataTemplateSelector` you can choose based on Class type that enters Template Selector what to do and what xaml / custom control to use for each item.
Than you can specify behaviour as hiding or showing on click for each item.
here is [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
about how to use it (its nearly same for ListView and for GridView)